# Error while saving Category in Magento 2.4.6-p1

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2.4

When I try to save a category I am getting cloudflare timeout error and the category is not getting saved. When I checked the exception log I found this error `: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction,   query was: UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET attribute_set_id = ?, parent_id = ?, created_at = ?, updated_at = ?, path = ?, position = ?, level =   ?, children_count = ? WHERE (entity_id = '1337')`. When I restart the mysql service and refresh the same page the category gets saved. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you running any other clients doing transactions on this database other than Magento? The lock wait timeout suggests some transaction was holding onto a lock for over 50 seconds (assuming the default timeout). I doubt Magento itself would do this, so I would look for another client. Either an app you wrote, or a MySQL query tool.

Comment: Magento has cron and elastic search, besides that I have written a small cron script. But my script gets executed only one time in a day. There is no other client.

Comment: Does your script complete? Or does it start a transaction and leave it uncommitted for a long time? Does your script query the `catalog_category_entity` table directly or any child table that references that table?

Comment: Yes. I am not using any transaction in my script. It doesn't query catalog_category_entity  or child tables

Comment: I searched and found a similar error reported here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147681/lock-wait-timeout-exceeded I had assumed that Magento itself would not cause a lock wait timeout, but apparently it can.